# Azure webapplication return 404 when try to access using the address bar or refresh page

Tags: azure, reactjs

I need a little help with my azure app, I have a **website** using ReactJS hosted on Azure, but something weird is happening.

The only page I can access using the address bar its the mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com. If I try access something like mydomain.com/login it **returns 404** and a white page with the follow message

```
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".
```

Another thing is that I can normally use the website if I start from home. Example, if i am at homepage and click at a button that sends me to /login works, but if I try to refresh or go directly from the address bar, does not work.

Now, I also have a staging at azure that has exactly the same code, and works just fine, I can access anything from anywhere.

There is anyone that know anything about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem, at staging azure app was a web.config file that was not created at the production app, that is why the problem existed, so after copy and paste the web.config file to production everything works just fine.

Comment: As it exceeds the comment text limit, I am posting the web.config file as separate answer

Comment: can you provide that config file ?

Answer (score 3):

Anyone facing the same issue can use the below `web.config` file which should be placed under the `/site/wwwroot` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your React `routing` not working properly.

You can bypass the problem by using Hash (#) in your URL:

example:

use `http://example.com/#/about` instead of `http://example.com/about`

and in your router you should have something like this:

```
render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="#/repos" component={Repos}/>
      <Route path="#/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

**Downsides:**

'ugly' URLs
Server-side rendering is not possible with this approach. As far as SEO is concerned, your website consists of a single page with hardly any content on it.

Comment: I tried that, but when I do this, i access the homepage if I use # before it. And at my other app I have the same code and works access using /about

Comment: that other app might have a url rewrite or something in the web config... or your web server fixes the issue somehow... did you say when you use /#/about it navigates to your home page?, now you should add the # to your router component... with just adding # to the url it will not work..

Comment: @WilliamCaetano I updated the answer with the change you need to do to the router code...