# Urls don't work on refresh withing React app hosted on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure

I have just noticed that in my react app the urls don't work when user refreshes the page. The weird things is that locally everything works fine. I have created the app using create-react-app. I was reading the [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) but since the build process is run automatically through github actions it is not clear how to solve this. Can anyone suggest a quick solution?

Comment: check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files

Comment: sorry, not sure how the above solve this problem.

Comment: it's a cache problem, you need to force users to download the latest version of JS file using one of the solutions from the link I've shared

Comment: I am not sure if I am explaning it properly, but the issue is that if for example, within the app user navigates to domain.com/login the page shows correctly. However, if he hits the refresh button, the 404 is shown from azure. It is not clear therefore how the cashing is thte problem

Comment: I see, it's a different problem then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052520/azure-webapplication-return-404-when-try-to-access-using-the-address-bar-or-refr

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the problem is `fallbackroutes` found on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration.
Add `staticwebapp.config.json` at the root folder of your react app with the below content and push to git:

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
   "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with GitHub pages and this is because the routes don't exist on the server and are handled by the frontend router.

I solved it by replacing the 404 page with my `index.html`. The `index.html` will load in react-router which in turn will handle the routing.

You could try to replace or redirect the Azure 404 page to your `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this file

> routes.json

with the below code

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ]
}
```